# How to Run Failed Jobs with new code in laravel

Tags: laravel, jobs

I have a list of failed jobs in the `failed_jobs` table that I need to run but with modified code.

I'm aware that the code is cached in the payload of the job. But is there a way to retry the job with the current code published? I've tried using

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

after

```
php artisan queue:restart
```

but to no success. Can someone tell me if it's even possible to run jobs that have failed but with newly modified code?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Can you post what you tried so far? That would help the community help you.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
  php artisan queue:retry all
```

Comment: This just uses the old code/data stored with the job in `failed_jobs`, as OP wrote - "*I'm aware that the code is cached in the payload of the job*".  It will not use new code, which is the whole point of the question.